# Should I bring HTML snippets or JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Please note: this is not exactly same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867163/the-ajax-response-data-json-xml-or-html-snippet). Although it looks like that, I have some very specific requirements.

In my application, I have two panels to update with a single AJAX request.
Currently, I am sending JSON, and constructing two DOMs in JS and appending them in corresponding places.

This is becoming difficult to maintain, and much processing is happening on the client side. So, I am thinking of sending HTML code snippet.

The problem here is that I have two panels, and with a single AJAX request, how should I bring two different HTML snippets for different panels?

Also: -

1) I am sending the AJAX request periodically after each 30 seconds, and also sending a CRC-32 of the data in the JSON. So, if there is no change in the data I don't have to recreate the DOM.

2) Replacing the old HTML, with new HTML suddenly flickers the page.

3) Each panel can have dynamic number of rows, and I have to attach some events from JavaScript side to each row. For this, it is easier if I have data in JSON format. But if I am switching to HTML snippet, how to do this?

Comment: OMG! I had an answer where is that gone?

Comment: They probably felt the answer wasn't pertinent or didn't like their answer so they removed it.

Answer (score 3):

[Taconite](http://malsup.com/jquery/taconite/) is something you should look into. It updates multiple HTML blocks with a single request.

http://malsup.com/jquery/taconite/